# Open file with part of name known

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have to

```
open(unit,file='x',status='old',action='read',iostat=io_error)
```

The problem is, i only know part of the name of the file since the last part is a number which changes every time the program is executed and I don't know the system in which the number is generated (extern library).

Is there a way to open the file with only a part of the name known?

Comment: Not in pure Fortran. You have to use other means to search the files in the directory. Probably something using shell. Which operating system do you use?

Comment: Ubuntu. Do you mean something like SYSTEM?

Comment: Yes, SYSTEM or EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE which is the standard statement. Create some bash script which will determine the right name and save it somewhere. Then read the saved filename in Fortran.

Comment: Or, perhaps easier, have a shell wrapper that first identifies the file and then calls the Fortran program passing the selected filename as a parameter. Or you could create a symlink (or even a hardlink) with a fixed name that points to the desired file on each run, and the Fortran uses the fixed name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll need to know the filename before you can open it.  One thing Fortran lacks in this regard is the ability to inspect the filesystem.  Your options boil down to

- `EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE` or `SYSTEM` to call external programs, or
- use `iso_c_binding` features to call C standard library functions.

I find the second option a bit cumbersome as the calls you'll need to make involve lots of typdef'd types, structures and C pointers.  It is certainly doable but won't be the most straightforward if you aren't already familiar with Fortran/C interop.

Calling `execute_command_line` or `system` is 'easier' in the sense that if you can write a shell command to find your filename then you already have a solution.

As an example, I have a library that reads HDF5 data with N files, where N is based upon model timesteps and may be irregular.  Rather than put the burden on the user to enumerate the files I was in a similar position as you.  The way I'd solve your version of the problem would be something like this:

```
character(len=*), parameter :: temporary_file = '/tmp/something_unique'
character(len=*) :: filename_fragment, filename
integer :: u

call execute_command_line('find . -name '//trim(filename_fragment)// &
                          "* -printf '%f\n' > "//trim(temporary_file)
open(newunit=u, file=temporary_file, action="read")
read(u, '(A)') filename
close(u)
```

If `filename_fragment` is the part of the name you know, this is little more than a call to `find` with output redirected.  E.g. if the filename_fragment is "datasetABC_" this would run

```
find . -name 'datasetABC_*' -printf '%f\n' > /tmp/something_unique
```

And the file `/tmp/something_unique` will contain one filename per line that matches your search. You may need to adjust the arguments to `find` to work for your specific case, but this is gives you the general idea of how to proceed.  Once you have this working, you just open `/tmp/something_unique` and read your full filename(s) from the file and now you know the full name to open them with.

* Note: the solution above assumes your `find` will return only one filename.  If it has multiple matches you'll need to either refine your search or handle that case within Fortran to get the correct file from the filenames in the temporary file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer I will look in it tomorrow. Since I'm already using iso_c_binding (the external library is in C/C++), maybe its not even that difficult. We'll see tomorrow.

Comment: the `execute_command_line('find......` worked fine on the first try! Thank you very much!